# How to read xml node value

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I'm have an xml file and am struggling to read value "my name" in c#
can anyone help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<doc:SomeReport xsi:schemaLocation="urn:tes:doc:Fsur.0.97 C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\rty0403\Desktop\Smaple%20Sampling%20Schemas\Testdoc.doc.0.97.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bie3="urn:tes:data:CommonAggregates:0.97" xmlns:bie1="urn:tes:data:SampleAggregates:0.97" xmlns:doc="urn:tes:doc:Fsur.0.97">
  <doc:family>
    <doc:first>my name</doc:first> 
  </doc:family>
</doc:SomeReport>
```

Comment: How are you trying to read the value? Care to give a code sample?

Comment: here you go , matches does not bring anything.
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(file);
XmlNodeList matches = xdoc.SelectNodes("//First");

Comment: Please update your question with any additional info you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [XPathSelectElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355.aspx) method:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
            var nameTable = reader.NameTable;
            var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
            namespaceManager.AddNamespace("doc", "urn:tes:doc:Fsur.0.97");
            var first = doc.XPathSelectElement("//doc:first", namespaceManager);
            Console.WriteLine(first.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin that works fine!!, just wondering whats the difference between using XDocument and XMLDocumnet like below               XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(file);
XmlNamespaceManager man = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
man.AddNamespace("doc", "urn:tes:doc:Fsur.0.97");
XmlNodeList matches = xdoc.SelectNodes("//doc:first", man);

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, you forgot to define the namespace before trying to select the node.

See [XML: Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498646/xml-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object/5498719#5498719) or [How to select xml root node when root node has attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856245/how-to-select-xml-root-node-when-root-node-has-attribute/5856346#5856346) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load(fileName); // load the desired xml file
XNamespace aw = "urn:tes:doc:Fsur.0.97"; // this is the namespace in your xml

var firstName = xml.Element(aw + "family").Element(aw + "first").Value;
```

This will only get you one element of type *family* and one element of type *first*.

Comment: how do I pass a  filename instead of text?

Comment: @melspring: `XElement xml = XElement.Load(filepath);`